# Rule cannot be matched when running flex to generate a lexical analyzer

Tags: flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I am trying to write a specification for a flex lexical analyzer. One of the rules is that the identifier (e.g., "foo", "Foo_Bar", "year_2020", "Jan30") cannot end with "_", such as "foo_".
So far I have the following to catch that error:

```
letter [A-Za-z]
digit [0-9]
identifier {letter}({letter}|{digit}|\_)*({letter}|{digit})*
number {digit}+
character [0-9a-zA-Z_]
```

...

```
    /*Ends with underscore*/
{letter}({character}*({letter}|{number})+)?\_
{
    printf("Error at line %d, column %d: identifier \"%s\" cannot end with an underscore.\n", num_lines, num_cols, yytext);
    exit(1);
}
```

However I am getting an error "mini_l.lex:89: warning, rule cannot be matched", line 89 is `{letter}({character}*({letter}|{number})+)?\_`.

Could someone please help me out?

Comment: Somewhat contradicting a prior comment of mine on another question, I wouldn't even write this rule. I wouldn't even have this rule in the language. I'm not in favour of lexical errors as a general rule, with the exception of unterminated quotes or comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message means that the preceding rules in your flex definition already cover every case which might be matched with this rule. Since you don't provide any information about the previous rules, it's not possible to suggest which rule or rules might be making this rule redundant, but that's what you should be looking for.

Also, please remember that in a flex definition, an action **must** start on the same line as the pattern. It is not possible to put the action on the next line, as you have done; that will cause the action to be misinterpreted as a pattern. So it's possible that the problem is actually the pattern `{`, since flex occasionally reports errors with a slightly-incorrect line number.

Comment: I realized that the original identifier covers the rule described by line 89, I had to fix the identifier. And thanks for the tips on the same line pattern.